# Wordpress and custom menu using wp_page_menu

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wpmu

I'm using the following code to add custom taxonomies to my menu in wordpress.  I need to make these "sub" items under Products.

Example right now they are showing up:

```
Photography > Lighting
Photography > Cameras
```

I need them to show up as

```
Products > Photography > Lighting
Products > Photography > Cameras
```

```
add_filter( 'wp_page_menu', 'custom_page_nav', 90 );
function custom_page_nav( $menu )
{
    $taxonomy = 'catalog';
    $orderby = 'name';
    $show_count = 0; // 1 for yes, 0 for no
    $pad_counts = 1; // 1 for yes, 0 for no
    $hierarchical = true; // 1 for yes, 0 for no
    $title = '';

    $args = array( 'taxonomy' => $taxonomy, 'orderby' => $orderby, 'show_count' => $show_count, 'pad_counts' => $pad_counts,
        'hierarchical' => $hierarchical, 'title_li' => false, 'echo' => false, 'empty' => true, 'hide_empty' => false,
        'depth' => 0 );
    $links .= wp_list_categories( $args );
    //  $links .= wp_list_categories( array( 'title_li' => false, 'echo' => false, 'empty' => true ) );
    $menu = str_replace( '', $links . '', $menu );
    return $menu;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using the "menus" feature in version 3.0? You can customize your menu very easily.

Comment: These menu items are created automatically by the plugin.  This works fairly well, but there are some problems when there are to many lower level links created.  Using the menus features really would not help unless you know how to programmically create the menu items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function custom_page_nav( $menu ){
    $taxonomy = 'catalog';
    $orderby = 'name';
    $show_count = 0; // 1 for yes, 0 for no
    $pad_counts = 1; // 1 for yes, 0 for no
    $hierarchical = 1; // 1 for yes, 0 for no
    $title = '';

    $args = array( 'taxonomy' => $taxonomy, 'orderby' => $orderby, 'show_count' => $show_count, 'pad_counts' => $pad_counts,
        'hierarchical' => $hierarchical, 'title_li' => false, 'echo' => false, 'empty' => true, 'hide_empty' => true,
        'depth' => 0 );
    $links .= wp_list_categories( $args );
    //  $links .= wp_list_categories( array( 'title_li' => false, 'echo' => false, 'empty' => true ) );
    $menu = str_replace( '', 'Prodcuts '.$links . '', $menu ); 
    //
    return $menu;
}
```